# Как сохранить пропорции 3D объекта в окне рендера OpenGL с перспективой?

Tags: c++, opengl

В [прошлый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575548) раз я узнавал о пропорциях 2D объекта. Теперь меня волнует тот же вопрос, но с 3D объектом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
#include <GL/glut.h> 

GLfloat xRotated, yRotated, zRotated;

void init(void) { 
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); //Сглаживание    
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
} 

void DrawCube(void) {  
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // очистить буфер рисования.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();   
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5); 
    glRotatef(yRotated,1.0,1.0,0.0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  

    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);    
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);   
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);   
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 

    glColor3f(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f);    
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);  
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);  
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);   
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);  

    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);          
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);      
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);          
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);     
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);    
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);     
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);          
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);    
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);     
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);      
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);    
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);     
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);     
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f); 

    glEnd();  

    glFlush(); 
}  

void animation(void) {  
    yRotated += 0.03;   

    DrawCube(); 
} 

void reshape(int x, int y) {  
    if (y == 0 || x == 0)
        return;       

    // Устанавливаем новую проекционную матрицу 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    // Угол обзора: 40 градусов   
    // Возле плоскости отсечения расстояние: 0,5   
    // Дальний отсечения плоскости расстояние: 20,0  

    gluPerspective(40.0,(GLdouble)x/(GLdouble)y,0.5,20.0);  
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);   
    glViewport(0,0,x,y);  // Использование всего окна для rendering
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    glutInit(&argc, argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]); 
    init(); 
    glutDisplayFunc(DrawCube);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); 
    glutIdleFunc(animation); 
    glutMainLoop();     
    return 0;
}
```

Как я понял всё дело в перспективе.

```
gluPerspective(40.0,(GLdouble)x/(GLdouble)y,0.5,20.0);
```

Так нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так не нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***БОНУСНЫЙ ВОПРОС:***

Существует ли какая-нибудь универсальная функция перспективы, которой часто пользуются? В плане мы вводим какой-нибудь один параметр (например угол обзора), а на его основе остальные сами высчитываются (дальность размещения, отсечение плоскости и т.д.).

Comment: так в чём проблема ? какой у вас результат выходит из тех двух ? тоесть пропорции сохраняются или не сохраняются ?

Comment: @ampawd Это всё один результат при изменение размеров окна.

Comment: как это один результат ? один и тотже код не может выдавать разные результаты ...

Comment: @ampawd один и тот же код *может* и обычно *будет* выдавать разные результаты при *разных* входных параметрах (например размерах области отрисовки), что мы тут и наблюдаем.

Answer (score 1):

Для расчета матрицы перспективы обычно используется угол *вертикального* обзора и соотношение сторон - `(GLdouble)x/(GLdouble)y`.

Для сохранения относительного размера модели в окне рендера, в случае когда окно более узкое, вам нужно строить перспективу с заданным ***горизонтальным*** углом обзора. Не уверен, есть ли такая функция в `glu`, поэтому в Delphi использую вот такую, для построения матрицы перспективы:

```
class function TMatrix3D.NewPerspectiveFovRH(const AFOV, AAspect, AZNear, AZFar: Single; const AHorizontalFOV: Boolean = False): TMatrix3D;
var
  XScale, YScale: Single;
begin
  if AHorizontalFOV then
  begin
    XScale := 1 / Tangent(AFOV / 2);
    YScale := XScale / AAspect;
  end else
  begin
    YScale := 1 / Tangent(AFOV / 2);
    XScale := YScale / AAspect;
  end;

  Result := TMatrix3D.Identity; // Получаем единичную матрицу
  Result.m11 := XScale;
  Result.m22 := YScale;
  Result.m33 := AZFar / (AZNear - AZFar);
  Result.m34 := -1;
  Result.m43 := AZNear * AZFar / (AZNear - AZFar);
  Result.m44 := 0;
end;
```

Как видите код достаточно простой. Далее эту матрицу надо передать в OpenGL для использования в качестве матрицы проекции.

Ответ не претендует на полноту, но надеюсь вы справитесь с переводом кода в C++ и передачей построенной матрицы в OpenGL.

---

Более простого способа задания перспективы нет, т.к. все 4 параметра независимы и необходимы. Но вы можете написать свою функцию-обертку, которая будет строить перспективу только по соотношению сторон, с константным углом обзора (например 45) и плоскостями Z отсечения (например 0.001 и 1000).