# Не получается сохранить пропорции при изменении размеров окна в OpenGL. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: c++, opengl

Доброго времени суток! Начал недавно учить OpenGl. Наткнулся на сохранение пропорций при изменении размеров окна. В общем, разобрался с glOrtho, glViewport, но всё равно **не работает сохранение пропорций в программе**. Вот пример простейшей программы:

```
void renderScene(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glRectf(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);

glFlush();
}

void changeSize(int w, int h)
{
if (h == 0)
    h=1;
glViewport(0,0,w,h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
float ratio = w/h;
if (w<=h)
    glOrtho (-100,100,-100/ratio, 100/ratio, 1,-1);
else
    glOrtho (-100*ratio,100*ratio, -100,100,1,-1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

int main (void)
{
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(500,500);

glutCreateWindow("he");
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
glClearColor(0,0,1,1);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Дело в том, что пропорции сохраняются в "определённых местах":
[без изменения размера http://savepic.ru/12914379.png](http://savepic.ru/12914379.png)
[размер изменён http://savepic.ru/12960458.png](http://savepic.ru/12960458.png)
[размер снова изменён http://savepic.ru/12954314.png](http://savepic.ru/12954314.png)

Comment: Нет, не дубликат. У человека то получилось сохранить пропорции с помощью всё тех же телодвижений с glOrtho, а у меня по всей видимости ошибка где-то, которую я в упор не нахожу.

Comment: Займитесь отладкой. Проверьте что к вам приходят правильные `w` и `h` и так далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ответу [Как сохранить пропорции 2D объекта в окне рендера OpenGL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575548/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-2d-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-opengl) и вашему коду, у вас не правильно вычисляется ratio. Насколько я понимаю при этом вычислении:

```
float ratio = w/h;
```

Используется целочисленное деление, т.е. если разделить 100 / 200 вы получите 0.0f. Следовательно вам необходимо явно указать использование "float деления".

```
float ratio = w/(float)h;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вовсе забыл о приведении типов данных. В pascal для целочисленного деления используются отдельные операторы, по этому привык, что знак / означает просто деление, а не целочисленное.