# Как делают одинаковое изображение при разных разрешениях?

Tags: opengl, opengles

Думал что надо экран делать вот так `glOrtho(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)`. Но тогда координаты для пикселя нужно выставлять в 0.001... и не понятно, будет ли при разных разрешениях одинаковое изображение. Вот хочу узнать, как делают для 2d и 3d одинаково?

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Уточните. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Что значит "одинаковое изображение"? Растянутое под размер экрана? Или с тем же размером в пикселях, но разными отступами?

Comment: Ну например есть изображение при разрешении 1920x1080, это изображение находиться посередине и не перекрывает область экрана. Но если изображение поместить на экран 1024x768, то оно уйдёт за край экрана и будет видна не полностью. Я как то читал что такую проблему как то решают. И на разных разрешениях, изображение будет посередине. Но как?

Comment: Ну, вы же сами сказали, можно посчитать точные координаты для углов четырехугольника. Вы спрашиваете как? Есть вариант сделать `ortho(0, ширина экрана, 0, высота экрана, -1, 1)`, и тогда координаты будут сразу измеряться в пикселях. Можно повторить эти вычисления без помощи матриц, самому.

Comment: А если изображение будет размером 1920x1080, то на экран в 1024x768 не поместить. Вот я например как то давно делал игру на unity3d. Изображение совсем немного различалось по ширине, а в целом было одинаковое, что на мониторе в 1920x1080, что на экране маленького телефона, где размер экрана 480x... не помню какое разрешение.

Comment: Похожий вопрос, только не про картинки, а про объекты, но суть та же - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575548